# How to remove highlight from Code rules in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper, highlight, code-analysis

We have been using Resharper for several years with our own set of rules. Some of them are always qualifying variables and methods with this. or ClassName.

Now with VS2015 this. and ClassName. are greyed out looking like there is something wrong (event if you deactivate the rules in the Code Analysis functionality which is annoying when you have to do it on every project you create):

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way to deactivate this unwanted coloring ´feature´?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable `this` coloring by setting Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Qualify member access with 'this'

Comment: Great, what about the class name in MainWindow.test?